# Можно ли использовать словари с командами?

Tags: python, словари

пытался написать функцию с черепашей графикой используя словарь вместо ветвления

```
import turtle
t = turtle.Turtle()
d = {'f':t.fd(50), '+':t.lt(90)}
for i in range(4):
    d['f']
    d['+']
```

но в итоге он рисует лишь одну линию и поворачивает черепаху, и на этом всё.
Можно ли вообще так использовать словарь или я ерундой занимаюсь?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Так вы создаете словарь `строка-результат функции`.
Чтобы вызывать функции используйте `lambda`:

```
import turtle
t = turtle.Turtle()
d = {
    'f': lambda: t.fd(50),
    '+': lambda: t.lt(90),
}
for i in range(4):
    d['f']()
    d['+']()
```

Еще так можно передать *заготовленной* функции значение:

```
import turtle
t = turtle.Turtle()
d = {
    'f': lambda x: t.fd(x),
    '+': lambda x: t.lt(x),
}
for i in range(4):
    d['f'](50)
    d['+'](90)
```